# performance comparison mPDF vs tcPDF

Tags: php, javascript, html, tcpdf, mpdf

I am using mPDF to generate PDF from html because i feel it is easy to use, I hear from one of senior that it is slower than that of tcPDF.

But after reading from both mPDF and tcPDF forums/documentations and searching from web I conclude that both are using same fPDF and fPDF is using  PDFlib library at back-end than how can they be different in their performance.

can anyone clear it if there is any difference?

Comment: Why don't you run some benchmark tests and let us know?

Comment: awm the problem is i never done that almost newbie in PHP , u guide me please how to do than surely I will do and share.

Comment: @Petah Is wkhtmlpdf is efficient from the two i mentioned??

Comment: @mansoor wkhtmlpdf is an external program that generates a PDF based on Webkit HTML rendering engine. http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: unless you're having a specific problem with performance, I'd recommend using the one you're most comfortable with rather than stressing about speed. Concentrate on writing good quality code first. Particularly if you're new to PHP. If you learn how to do it right, the performance will follow naturally